# Connect Azure database to existing Asp.Net web application

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, windows, azure

I'm actually working on an university project and have to figure out how to connect my windows azure database to an already existing ASP.net web application project.

The web application should run on smartphones and tablets. 
Since this is a group project, we use TFVC to manage the project.

Our client supplied an mysql script that will create the tables needed.
The Database is hosted in Azure and we want to access it through Visual Studio ultimate, so we can reveice data from the DB and integrate it's data in the application.

I also got the connection string, so I could use it if needed.

*So my question is:*
How can I connect to the database through visual studio and afterwards: how can I access to it? With access I mean, how and where can I use SQL queries in Visual Studio?

I don't really know where to start, whether it is connecting to the DB via code or on another way.

Every kind of help is welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As far as your question goes, I'm not sure what you're asking. Please edit your question with extra details such as: Where your existing asp.net app is running (is it in Azure? On-premises?) whether your db is is in a VM or an instance of SQL Database service; etc. Also; What have you tried, and what challenge are you running into?

Comment: Okay, it tried to explain my problem. Is it easier to understand now?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still quite vague on specifics of what you want to achieve but hopefully this answers it. If not, please provide even more detail on your question.

If you just want to see the DB in Visual Studio and interact with it

1. Download the Azure SDK
2. Go to Tools > Connect To Database

A side box will open and you can navigation through Azure then to your database.

Personally I prefer using SQL Server Management Studio, its much more responsive that the UI through Visual Studio.

If you want to connect your application to Azure, as in code an application that talks to a database, then you just need to replace the connection string in your Web.Config to your Azure Connection String. Then either use ADO.NET, Entity Framework or another ORM.

I recommend Entity Framework but it all depends on what your circumstances and project requirements are.

If the DB already has its schema defined get started here:
https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database

If its empty you can use code first:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I've needed. I will try it later on and respond to your suggestion. Thank you very much! :)